# Creating form with special fields

Tags: oracle-apex

I have to make an exercise for my examination but I can not find the solution. We have to create the following form:

The solution:

wijngroep: with al the unique names of the table wijngroepen (select list)

WIJNEN: with the unique names of the table wijnen based on the previous field (select list)

Wijn: combination of the jaar and inhoud field bases on previous field (select list)

So this seems very easy but now:

1) Load al groups of the wine (I know that one)

2) If you select a group then the name (WIJNEN) is filled in automatically

3) If you select a name (WIJNEN) then the Wijn-field (that exists out of the 'jaar' and 'inhoud' field as you can see in the pictures bellow) is automatically filled in.

There is my problem, I don't know how to combine the fields into one field and my dynamic actions do not work. Can someone help me?

Table Wijnen:
Wijnid
Jaar
Naam
Omschrijving
GroepsID
Inhoud
...

Table Wijngroepen:
GroepsID
Groepsnaam

Images are available in following links:

[solution](http://postimg.org/image/52iy2s5j3/)

and

[tables](http://postimg.org/image/c70rbtcsf/)

I have made an workspace:

```
name workspace =  EXEC
Username =  de.geyter.steffen@gmail.com
Password =  dummy
```

The tables are loaded into te application.

Comment: Is there a picture somewhere since you mention it? Can you edit your question to include? What does the form have to look like? Select lists? Reports? Do you have a somewhat-working application? The ideal situation would be you having or creating an app on apex.oracle.com and sharing the workspace and a developer account with us so we can look.

Comment: I have changed my post and now you have everything you asked :)

Comment: created demo page in your application 16747, page 3, check application and change as per suggested...

Comment: Changed it a bit and added some comment there

Comment: To make it more clear: I have found an example on 

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/05/oracle-apex-101-cascading-select-lists-dynamic-actions.html

This is what I want but I can not find the solution and they do not explain it very well on that link

Answer (score 0):

This should work to combine the fields

```
select distinct to_char(JAAR)||' '||NAAM as display_value, NAAM as return_value
```

from WIJNEN
 order by 1

I had a look at the application - apart from creating form what is the purpose. Remember a form only works on one record at a time

Comment: The only problem I still have now is the checkboxes. How do I get the values from my table into a checkbox.